# Azure Synapse Lake Database Not Appearing in Built Serverless Pool List

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I have created a new Azure Lake Database using the following procedure
[image]

The Lake Database name is called TestLakeDB.

However, when I check the list of databases available  in **Use database** TestLakeDB doesn't appear.
[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried to reload and check if it's still not showing in the drop-down list?

Comment: Hi Saideep, thanks for getting in touch. I have tried multiple refreshes, but nothting appears. I take it from your question, it should appear, correct?

Comment: Yes, can you please try reloading the entire synapse studio and check again?

Comment: Completely reloaded and still nothing.

Comment: Does it matter if I create the Lake Database while in my Github workspace? Or do I have create a Lake Database in while in Synapse Live mode?

Comment: When using Github workspace and creating a lake database, it is not showing in the dropdown, where as it is reflecting without any issue when used with synapse live mode.

Comment: Did you actually create the Lake Database while in Github mode?

Comment: I tried in both ways. The database created in live mode can be seen in the dropdown, but not the one created when connected to github workspace.

Comment: ok, I needed to create the Lake Database while in Synapse Live Mode. After that I was able to view it while in GitHub. Thanks

Comment: I wonder if you can help out with the other issue I'm having with the Lake Database in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133942/azure-synapse-serverless-pool-operation-drop-function-is-not-allowed-for-a-repli

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246808/discussion-between-saideeparikontham-mt-and-patterson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the valuable discussion. **Posting your conversation as answer** to help other community members who faces similar issues.

When we create Lake database after connecting to the github, it won't reflect in the Use Database because it is created in github mode.

[image]

To reflect the the Lake Database, create the database in the synapse live mode and connect to the github. Now we can see it reflects our database named `Lake_Database1` which is created in synapse live mode in the Use Database.

[image]