# Azure Synapse Serverless Pool Operation DROP FUNCTION is not allowed for a replicated database

Tags: azure-synapse

When I attempt to execute the following DROP FUNCTION on Azure Synapse Serverless Pool I get the following error

```
Operation DROP FUNCTION is not allowed for a replicated database
```

The code that generates the error is:

```
DECLARE @FunctionScript nvarchar(max) = 'IF object_id(N''dbo.GetOptionSetLabel'') is not null DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[GetOptionSetLabel]'
```

Any thoughts on how to overcome the error?

I think I got marked down on this question because I didn't include the full code, so here it is...

```
USE [LakeDatabaseEnriched] --Specify the name of the database in which GetOptionSetLabel function will be created
DECLARE 
    @OptionSetLabelFunctionDatabase sysname, --It will be automatically be set with the name of the database that has GetOptionSetLabel function 
    @OptionSetLabelFunctionDatabaseSchema sysname, --Specify the name of the database in which GetOptionSetLabel function will be created
    @OptionSetLabelFunctionDatabaseCollation varchar(256), --It will be automatically be set with the collation of the database that has GetOptionSetLabel function 
    @SynapseLinkDatabase sysname, --Specify the name of the database corresponding to your Synapse Link for Dataverse
    @CurrentDatabaseCollation varchar(256) 

SET @OptionSetLabelFunctionDatabase = QUOTENAME(DB_NAME())
SET @OptionSetLabelFunctionDatabaseCollation = CONVERT(varchar(256), DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'collation')); 
SET @OptionSetLabelFunctionDatabaseSchema = 'dbo'
SET @SynapseLinkDatabase = 'dataverse_xxxx_org5a2bcccf'

DECLARE @FunctionScript nvarchar(max) = 'IF object_id(N''dbo.GetOptionSetLabel'') is not null DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[GetOptionSetLabel]'

EXEC sp_executesql @FunctionScript

SET @FunctionScript = '
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 

SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
'

EXEC sp_executesql @FunctionScript

SET @FunctionScript = '

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetOptionSetLabel]
(
     @EntityName nvarchar(max), @ColumnName nvarchar(max), @Value nvarchar(max), @LanguageCode int
)
RETURNS 
nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @Values table (
         value nvarchar(max)
    );

    insert into @Values
    SELECT Value 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Value, '';'')

    declare @Labels table(
        AttributeValue int,
        LabelText nvarchar(max)
    );

    insert into @Labels
    select distinct *
    from (
    select gosm.[Option], gosm.LocalizedLabel Value
    from '+@SynapseLinkDatabase+'.'+@OptionSetLabelFunctionDatabaseSchema+'.GlobalOptionsetMetadata gosm
    inner join @Values v on cast(v.[Value] as int) = gosm.[Option]
    where gosm.OptionSetName = @ColumnName
    and gosm.LocalizedLabelLanguageCode = @LanguageCode
    and TRY_CAST(v.[Value] as int) is not null
    
    union
    
    select osm.[Option], osm.LocalizedLabel Value
    from '+@SynapseLinkDatabase+'.'+@OptionSetLabelFunctionDatabaseSchema+'.OptionsetMetadata osm
    inner join @Values v on cast(v.[Value] as int) = osm.[Option]
    where osm.OptionSetName = @ColumnName
    and osm.EntityName = @EntityName
    and osm.LocalizedLabelLanguageCode = @LanguageCode
    and TRY_CAST(v.[Value] as int) is not null
    ) t
    order by [Option] asc

    declare @optionsetLabel nvarchar(max)

    set @optionsetLabel = isnull(
    (
    select string_agg(LabelText, '', '')
    from @Labels
    ),
    @Value)

    RETURN @optionsetLabel

END'

PRINT 'Beginning function creation'
--PRINT @FunctionScript
EXEC sp_executesql @FunctionScript
PRINT 'Completed function creation'

USE [dataverse_xxxx_org5a2bcccf] --Specify the name of the database corresponding to your Synapse Link for Dataverse to be used from here onward

--=================================================================================================
--PROVIDE INPUT PARAMETERS:
--=================================================================================================

DECLARE
    @EnrichedViewDatabase sysname, --Specify the name of the database in which views with enriched entities will be created
    @EnrichedViewSchema sysname, --Specify the name of the database schema in which views with enriched entities will be created
    @EnrichedColumnSuffix varchar(50),  --Specify the suffix for columns enriched with human-readable descriptions. For example, the suffix of "label" will change a statecode column in the base table to a statelabel column in the enriched view.
    @LanguageCode varchar(10), --Specify the language code for localized labels. For example, English - United States is 1033 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oe376/6c085406-a698-4e12-9d4d-c3b0ee3dbc4a)
    @BaseTableSuffix varchar(50), --If applicable, specify the suffix in the names of the base tables or views (e.g., '_partitiond'). The default is an empty string.
    @PreviewOnly bit --Indicate whether to preview the SQL Script (without creating the views) = 1 ; Create views = 0;

SET @EnrichedViewDatabase = 'LakeDatabaseEnriched'
SET @EnrichedViewSchema = 'dbo'
SET @EnrichedColumnSuffix = 'label'
SET @LanguageCode = 1033
SET @BaseTableSuffix = ''
SET @PreviewOnly = 0
SET @CurrentDatabaseCollation = CONVERT(varchar(256), DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'collation'));  

-- 'If still collation error occurs in script, search for Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8 and replace it with getting collation from (SELECT @CurrentDatabaseCollation) query

--=================================================================================================
-- Do not edit the script below this point
--=================================================================================================

--Get column metadata from the Lake Database managed by Synapse Link for Dataverse
--The column metadata will be stored as a JSON document in a scalar variable
--This is needed as a workaround for the limitation of not allowing system objects to be used in distributed queries
DECLARE @ColumnMetadata nvarchar(MAX), @ColumnMetadataSQL nvarchar(MAX)

--Define the SQL statement to retrieve column metadata from the Lake Database managed by Synapse Link for Dataverse
--Results will be stored as a JSON document in a variable
SET @ColumnMetadataSQL = 'SET @ColumnMetadataOUT = (
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, 
    TABLE_NAME, 
    COLUMN_NAME, 
    ORDINAL_POSITION, 
    DATA_TYPE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo''
    AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN (''OptionsetMetadata'', ''GlobalOptionsetMetadata'',''StateMetadata'',''StatusMetadata'', ''TargetMetadata'')
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE ''%' + (@BaseTableSuffix COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) + '''
FOR JSON AUTO)'
DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX);  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@ColumnMetadataOUT NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT';  
EXECUTE sp_executesql @ColumnMetadataSQL, @ParmDefinition, @ColumnMetadataOUT=@ColumnMetadata OUTPUT;  

--Declare a variable to store a SQL statement for creating enriched views
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = ''

; WITH CM AS (
--Parse column metadata variable and construct a table based on its content
SELECT JSON_VALUE(CM.value, '$.TABLE_SCHEMA') AS TableSchema,
     JSON_VALUE(CM.value, '$.TABLE_NAME') AS TableName,
     LEFT(JSON_VALUE(CM.value, '$.TABLE_NAME'), LEN(JSON_VALUE(CM.value, '$.TABLE_NAME'))-LEN(@BaseTableSuffix)) AS EntityName,
     JSON_VALUE(CM.value, '$.COLUMN_NAME') AS ColumnName,
     CAST(JSON_VALUE(CM.value, '$.ORDINAL_POSITION') AS INT) AS OrdinalPosition,
     JSON_VALUE(CM.value, '$.DATA_TYPE') AS DataType
FROM OPENJSON (@ColumnMetadata) AS CM
)

, OSM AS (
--Get Option Set Metadata
SELECT DISTINCT 
    EntityName, 
    OptionSetName, 
    QUOTENAME(EntityName + '_' + OptionSetName) AS Alias
FROM dbo.[OptionsetMetadata]
WHERE LocalizedLabelLanguageCode = @LanguageCode
)

, GOSM AS (
--Get Global Option Set Metadata
SELECT DISTINCT 
    OptionSetName, 
    QUOTENAME('Global_' + OptionSetName) AS Alias
FROM dbo.[GlobalOptionsetMetadata]
WHERE LocalizedLabelLanguageCode = @LanguageCode
)

, GOSMM AS (
--Get Global Option Set Metadata
SELECT DISTINCT 
    OptionSetName, 
    QUOTENAME('Global_Multiselect_' + OptionSetName) AS Alias
FROM dbo.[GlobalOptionsetMetadata]
WHERE LocalizedLabelLanguageCode = @LanguageCode
)

, StateM AS (
--Get State Metadata
SELECT DISTINCT 
    EntityName, 
    QUOTENAME(EntityName + '_State') AS Alias
FROM dbo.[StateMetadata]
WHERE LocalizedLabelLanguageCode = @LanguageCode
)

, StatusM AS (
--Get Status Metadata
SELECT DISTINCT 
    EntityName,
    QUOTENAME(EntityName + '_Status') AS Alias
FROM dbo.[StatusMetadata]
WHERE LocalizedLabelLanguageCode = @LanguageCode
)

, SQLStatement AS (
--Enumerate all lines in the source table and replace codes with labels where applicable
SELECT CM.EntityName,
    --Before the first column of each table, construct a CREATE OR ALTER VIEW statement
    CASE WHEN CM.OrdinalPosition = 1
        THEN 'CREATE OR ALTER VIEW ' + QUOTENAME(@EnrichedViewSchema) + '.' + CM.EntityName + '
        AS
        SELECT '
        ELSE '  ,'
        END
    --For each column, check if it needs to be replaced with a suitable localized label
    + CASE 
        WHEN OSM.OptionSetName IS NOT NULL THEN OSM.Alias + '.[LocalizedLabel] AS ' + REPLACE(QUOTENAME(CM.ColumnName), 'code]', (@EnrichedColumnSuffix COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) + ']')
        WHEN GOSM.OptionSetName IS NOT NULL THEN GOSM.Alias + '.[LocalizedLabel] AS ' + REPLACE(QUOTENAME(CM.ColumnName), 'code]', (@EnrichedColumnSuffix COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) + ']')
        --Uncomment below if you want to show _value columns as well
        --WHEN GOSMM.OptionSetName IS NOT NULL THEN '[Base].' + QUOTENAME(CM.ColumnName) + ' as ' + CM.ColumnName + '_value, ' + ((@OptionSetLabelFunctionDatabase COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) + '.' + (@OptionSetLabelFunctionDatabaseSchema COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) + '.GetOptionSetLabel(''' + CM.TableName + ''', ''' + CM.ColumnName + ''', '+ '[Base].' + QUOTENAME(CM.ColumnName) + ', ' + @LanguageCode + ') as ' + CM.ColumnName)
        --Comment below if you want to show _value columns as well
        WHEN GOSMM.OptionSetName IS NOT NULL THEN ((@OptionSetLabelFunctionDatabase COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) + '.' + (@OptionSetLabelFunctionDatabaseSchema COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) + '.GetOptionSetLabel(''' + CM.TableName + ''', ''' + CM.ColumnName + ''', '+ '[Base].' + QUOTENAME(CM.ColumnName) + ', ' + @LanguageCode + ') as ' + CM.ColumnName)
        WHEN StateM.EntityName IS NOT NULL THEN StateM.Alias + '.[LocalizedLabel] AS ' + REPLACE(QUOTENAME(CM.ColumnName), 'code]', (@EnrichedColumnSuffix COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) + ']')
        WHEN StatusM.EntityName IS NOT NULL THEN StatusM.Alias + '.[LocalizedLabel] AS ' + REPLACE(QUOTENAME(CM.ColumnName), 'code]', (@EnrichedColumnSuffix COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) + ']')
        ELSE '[Base].' + QUOTENAME(CM.ColumnName)
        END AS [SQLLine],
    CM.OrdinalPosition
FROM CM 
    LEFT JOIN OSM
        ON CM.EntityName = OSM.EntityName
        AND CM.ColumnName = OSM.OptionSetName
        AND CM.DataType LIKE '%int' --Only include columns with integer data type
    LEFT JOIN GOSM
        ON CM.ColumnName = GOSM.OptionSetName
        AND CM.DataType LIKE '%int' --Only include columns with integer data type
    LEFT JOIN GOSMM
        ON CM.ColumnName = GOSMM.OptionSetName
        AND CM.DataType LIKE '%varchar%' --Only include columns with varchar data type that can potentially have multiselect values
    LEFT JOIN StateM
        ON CM.EntityName = StateM.EntityName
        AND CM.ColumnName = 'statecode'
        AND CM.DataType LIKE '%int' --Only include columns with integer data type
    LEFT JOIN StatusM
        ON CM.EntityName = StatusM.EntityName
        AND CM.ColumnName = 'statuscode'
        AND CM.DataType LIKE '%int' --Only include columns with integer data type

UNION ALL
--Construct the first line of the FROM clause, referencing external tables created by Synapse Link for Dataverse
SELECT DISTINCT
CM.EntityName,
'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + '.' + QUOTENAME(CM.TableSchema) + '.' + QUOTENAME(CM.TableName) + ' AS Base' AS SQLLine,
10000 AS OrdinalPosition
FROM CM

UNION ALL 
--Construct LEFT JOIN statements for each relevant OptionSetMetadata field
SELECT DISTINCT OSM.EntityName AS EntityName,
'   LEFT JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + '.[dbo].[OptionSetMetadata] AS ' + OSM.Alias + ' 
        ON ' + OSM.Alias + '.EntityName = ''' + OSM.EntityName + ''' 
        AND ' + OSM.Alias + '.OptionSetName = ''' +  OSM.OptionSetName + '''
        AND [Base].' + QUOTENAME(OSM.OptionSetName) + ' = ' + OSM.Alias + '.[Option]
        AND ' + OSM.Alias + '.LocalizedLabelLanguageCode = ' + @LanguageCode + '' AS SQLLine,
20000 AS OrdinalPosition
FROM OSM
    JOIN CM
        ON CM.EntityName = OSM.EntityName
        AND CM.ColumnName = OSM.OptionSetName
WHERE CM.DataType LIKE '%int' --Only capture columns with Integer Data Types

UNION ALL 
--Construct LEFT JOIN statements for each relevant GlobalOptionSetMetadata field
SELECT DISTINCT CM.EntityName AS EntityName,
'   LEFT JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + '.[dbo].[GlobalOptionSetMetadata] AS ' + Alias + ' 
        ON ' + Alias + '.OptionSetName = ''' +  OptionSetName + '''
        AND [Base].' + QUOTENAME(OptionSetName) + ' = ' + Alias + '.[Option]
        AND ' + Alias + '.LocalizedLabelLanguageCode = ' + @LanguageCode + '' AS SQLLine,
30000 AS OrdinalPosition
FROM GOSM
    JOIN CM
        ON CM.ColumnName = GOSM.OptionSetName
WHERE CM.DataType LIKE '%int' --Only capture columns with Integer Data Types

UNION ALL 
--Construct LEFT JOIN statements for each relevant State Metadata field
SELECT DISTINCT CM.EntityName AS EntityName,
'   LEFT JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + '.[dbo].[StateMetadata] AS ' + StateM.Alias + ' 
        ON ' + StateM.Alias + '.EntityName = ''' + StateM.EntityName + ''' 
        AND [Base].statecode' + ' = ' + StateM.Alias + '.[State]
        AND ' + StateM.Alias + '.LocalizedLabelLanguageCode = ' + @LanguageCode + '' AS SQLLine,
40000 AS OrdinalPosition
FROM StateM
    JOIN CM
        ON CM.EntityName = StateM.EntityName
        AND CM.ColumnName = 'statecode'
WHERE CM.DataType LIKE '%int' --Only capture columns with Integer Data Types

UNION ALL
--Construct LEFT JOIN statements for each relevant Status Metadata field
SELECT DISTINCT CM.EntityName AS EntityName,
'   LEFT JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()) + '.[dbo].[StatusMetadata] AS ' + StatusM.Alias + ' 
        ON ' + StatusM.Alias + '.EntityName = ''' + StatusM.EntityName + ''' 
        AND [Base].statuscode' + ' = ' + StatusM.Alias + '.[Status]
        AND ' + StatusM.Alias + '.LocalizedLabelLanguageCode = ' + @LanguageCode + '' AS SQLLine,
40000 AS OrdinalPosition
FROM StatusM
    JOIN CM
        ON CM.EntityName = StatusM.EntityName
        AND CM.ColumnName = 'statuscode'
WHERE CM.DataType LIKE '%int' --Only capture columns with Integer Data Types

UNION ALL
--Add statement terminator
SELECT DISTINCT
EntityName,
'; ' + CHAR(10) AS SQLLine,
100000 AS OrdinalPosition
FROM CM
)

--Construct individual statements to create views (1 view per row)
--Since CREATE VIEW statement must be the first statement in a batch, assign each view definition to a variable 
--and use the EXEC(@variable) command to create view as part of its own, separate batch.
, ViewDefinitions AS (
SELECT 'DECLARE @' + EntityName + ' NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
    ' + REPLACE(STRING_AGG(CAST(SQLLine as varchar(MAX)), CHAR(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EntityName, OrdinalPosition, SQLLine), '''', '''''') + ''' ' + CHAR(10) + 'EXEC [' + (@EnrichedViewDatabase COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8) + '].dbo.sp_executesql @' + EntityName + CHAR(10) AS ViewDefinition
FROM SQLStatement
GROUP BY EntityName
)

--Construct a comprehensive SQL statement to create all views
SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(ViewDefinition, ';' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(10))
FROM ViewDefinitions

--Return a preview of the SQL Script to be generated or go ahead and create the views.
IF @PreviewOnly = 1
BEGIN
    --Return the final SQL statement
    SELECT '--================================================================================================='+ CHAR(10) +' ' + CHAR(10) AS [--SQL Statement]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '-- A preview of the script to generate enriched views is provided below.'  AS [--SQL Statement]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '-- No database objects have been created.' AS [--SQL Statement]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '-- Re-run this script with the @PreviewOnly parameter set to 0 to actually create the views.' AS [--SQL Statement]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '--================================================================================================='+ CHAR(10) +' ' + CHAR(10) AS [--SQL Statement]
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT VALUE AS [--SQL Statement] FROM STRING_SPLIT((@SQL COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8), CHAR(10))
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --Execute the SQL statement
    PRINT 'Beginning views creation'
    --PRINT @SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    PRINT 'Completed views creation'
END
```

Comment: Can you create another database to house the function and cross-database join to hit the views in the other database?

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for reaching out. I'm not sure how that will resolve this issue? The already executes on two different databases

Comment: you may be right. But instead of troubleshooting a 200 line complex script with dynamic SQL I would start with a 5 line script and make sure you can create a simple function in a new database. Make sure the USE statement is run separately so you are definitely in the separate database.

Comment: Hi Greg, I'm certain the issue is ```DECLARE @FunctionScript nvarchar(max) = 'IF object_id(N''dbo.GetOptionSetLabel'') is not null DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[GetOptionSetLabel]'```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Operation DROP FUNCTION is not allowed for a replicated database

In Synapse Serverless SQL there are some operations are not allowed

You may see above problems while attempting to create SQL objects, users, or alter permissions in a database. When **you attempt to create objects in a database that is shared with the Spark pool, this error** is given. Read-only databases are replicated from Apache Spark pools. **A replicated database we cannot create new objects added using T-SQL.**

To workaround this, create a custom SQL database (serverless) that will contain the custom schemas, views, and functions that will reference Lake database external tables using the 3-part names.

Refer - [Operation isn't allowed for a replicated database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand?tabs=x80070002#operation-isnt-allowed-for-a-replicated-database)

Comment: While true, more often than not Synapse started out by default on the database 'master' or 'default', while I'm using db01.
So be sure before doing big stuff like above to check that the connection properties in the top of your screen are correct.