# Synapse Lake Database not reflected in Serverless Database List

Tags: azure-synapse

I created a Lake Database in Synapse, that I can't query because it is not reflected on the list of available Databases.

[Screenshot of Synapse Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7mHE.png)

All changes have been published and I have reloaded the page many times.

My Problem is similar to the one posted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73133719/azure-synapse-lake-database-not-appearing-in-built-serverless-pool-list), with the difference that I don't use a Github Repository. The Database was created in Synapse Live mode.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I reproduced this and for me It is reflecting fine after publishing the Lake databases. Make sure you are refreshing the Use database option. https://i.imgur.com/h3bbp7W.png

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. I've done several tests, always publishing the database without luck. My process follows the lines described in this article: https://www.sqlshack.com/getting-started-with-azure-synapse-lake-database-and-lake-tables/.

Comment: I have gone through the above link and its fine. But this seems to be an internal issue in your subscription. Try contacting MS support to check if there is any problem.